# golang print echo.Context values

Tags: go, go-echo

I'm brand new to Go and trying to inspect a method argument. I've got the following code

```
func (c *controller) OrderNew(ctx echo.Context) error {
```

When I try either:

```
    fmt.println(ctx)
    fmt.Printf("%v \n", ctx)
```

I get

```
&{0xc4200f21e0 0xc4202302d0 /order [] [] map[] 0x4092860 map[site_key:2] 0xc4200bb6c0}
```

I realize *controller is a pointer and the values returned contain addresses, but not sure how to really debug or inspect further. I also see functions called on cxt like

```
ctx.Get and ctx.Render
```

which I realize are functions in echo.Context

Any help/clarification is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is it exactly you expect to see? `echo.Context` has a lot of methods you can call to get whatever information you want.

Comment: Here is a link to echo's [context.go](https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/context.go) for your convenience. Also, if I had to guess, the most interesting methods might be Request() and Response() which retrieve the HTTP Request and Response objects respecively.

Comment: Or a link to the nicer formatted godoc: [`echo.Context`](https://godoc.org/github.com/labstack/echo#Context)

Answer (score 2):

use `log` package.

```
log.Printf("CONTEXT %+v", ctx)
```

Comment: Add a playground link to explain it by example.

Answer (score 0):

- https://echo.labstack.com/guide/context is an excellent source for looking into echo.
- offline there is `godoc` functionality, which helps with understanding any package(which is downloaded in your machine). In your case this can be done, `godoc github.com/labstack/echo Context` on your command line.
- There are GOTO functionalities many editors that lets you see the library source, while you are coding, https://github.com/fatih/vim-go, https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime are such examples. What they allow you to do is to navigate these functions and structs to the point where they are defined. Hopefully, someone will have written, a crisp documentary comment there.
- if all you want is to watch the execution of your code, you can use debugging tools, like delve https://github.com/derekparker/delve.